# verify google IdToken with jwt-cpp

Tags: c++, google-cloud-platform, google-authentication, jwk

How to verify google tokenId jwt with jwt-cpp lib or something else lib on c++? I tried to redo the example from the library on github, but I don't have enough knowledge in tokens to do everything right, that's what I got:

```
  std::string raw_jwks =
            R"({
  "keys": [
    {
      "kid": "486f16482005a2cdaf26d9214018d029ca46fb56",
      "e": "AQAB",
      "n": "pKFKLmDnNozPu24-nCrbvbBjO0gith7VmxPm1px9lkJfwXOWEbNzyfDhd3SjylKTyH5lq6zMtJvNvKCr2TyQTwypvmZBpeMK29Zz0WvgPBFJ6HHsu9apa21hgE9iPf0A1lNG5Nd2kP9m2Kc8ekKy4OrshDp6gs1ntHPWiW2iSjttruFjTB20P7p5GTdlxzg6LCrJ03E7FJlrfXcEEKRDzZ4h3b6hN2aZ_heOZxRSZ6Uwx8_tbFRe2TIfw9IXaXXuodHMRottSIZBtdJdOanbIFAuhEev9b-lFTksFQXDvicUiz_ri4JDliGuEAgINHjI6pcNo2vkYx3NupROmkDRIQ",
      "use": "sig",
      "alg": "RS256",
      "kty": "RSA"
    },
    {
      "kty": "RSA",
      "alg": "RS256",
      "n": "h0G4nnQc39gn04fTuSJB6l1JhE9ggG-SHrc9yfr85tzQEjxG55jipmnmW1x-IHS1PvWgtNbpeEDya9IUzkC8BxnBht7WVDV9mLBZK8szrCrj6l7SwvQOM6cw0-KgGgmzwE_IGkn452wmlVYz9IIY-etasrkstJ0G2smQJ3Db3YbZe32FoYnXbbK38O2hIf4bffegccrfmsEEbSisq0903IEbCi0qpJbhrgqvYg6_y0KeOxxX5u-_Jg-KM0Aub4YGT2LRsiE_ygskabuoh6nQDr8M9-SDC_bEind2FUk761ZSw_QMk9_Nc9orllaMZpQ4FpKRv5LXHUawz_er8P3c0w",
      "use": "sig",
      "kid": "38f3883468fc659abb4475f36313d22585c2d7ca",
      "e": "AQAB"
    }
  ]
}
)";

        std::string token =
            "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9."
            "eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ."
            "SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c";

        auto decoded_jwt = jwt::decode(token);
        auto jwks = jwt::parse_jwks(raw_jwks);
        auto jwk = jwks.get_jwk(decoded_jwt.get_key_id());

        auto issuer = decoded_jwt.get_issuer();
        auto x5c = jwk.get_x5c_key_value();

        if (!x5c.empty() && !issuer.empty()) {
            auto verifier =
                jwt::verify()
                    .allow_algorithm(jwt::algorithm::rs256(jwt::helper::convert_base64_der_to_pem(x5c), "", "", ""))
                    .with_issuer(issuer)
                    .leeway(60UL); // value in seconds, add some to compensate timeout

            verifier.verify(decoded_jwt);
        }
```

But i have no x5c  in JWK, only "e" and "n", what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array in your question **raw_jwks** is a JSON Web Key Set (JWKS). This contains an array of public keys. The key ID is either **kid** which you have or commonly **x5c**.

Some libraries accept a public key in the raw number format (n and e), others require that you create a public key in PKCS format from those numbers first. I do not use your library, so consult the documentation for the required format and conversion functions.

Since you do not know the actual private key ID used to sign the JWT you must loop thru **raw_jwks** checking each one for signature validation success. If neither succeeds, report failure.

**For future information**, in Google Cloud there are two types of private/public keys. Those managed by Google Cloud (only the public key is available) and service account keys.

The public keys for Google Cloud are located here:

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs

For service accounts they start with this URL and have the service account email address appended:

https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/

Comment: Thank you for the answer! it's pretty clear. Yesterday I'm found that i can use PEM keys for validate google IdToken, that's easier to use. Сould you suggest resources for studying materials about tokens? Although I am a desktop / mobile developer and it is unlikely that they will ever be useful to me again, but it is still interesting to find out how to work with them and what they have inside, I will be grateful.

Comment: @Deymoss - Google Search. There are lots of resources. I recommend starting with two popular usage cases: SSL/TLS certificates and SSH key pairs. You will use those technologies all the time. They are not JWTs but use the same technology.